# Find the binomial coefificient of $x^8$ in $(1+x^2-x^3)^9$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I was trying to solve it using the multinomial theorem.

I was trying to find which combinations could give me such $x^8$

and I came to the conclusion that it only occours when i take
 $(x^2)^4$ or $(-x^3)^2*(x^2)^1$

therefore: $\binom{9!}{0!*4!*0!} + \binom{9!}{0!*1!*2!}$

It just seems just too big of a number.. what am I missing?

Comment: It seems you entered the factorials into the multinomial coefficients instead of the plain numbers. Like $9!$ instead of $9$ etc. That way you surely get huge wrong results. So, I wrote the answer with the correct numbers within the multinomial coefficients. Maybe this helps to clear up the situation.

Answer (score 2):

A comparison.  It is convenient to  use the *coefficient  of* operator $[x^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^n$.

> **Multinomial theorem:**
>
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{[x^8]}&\color{blue}{\left(1+x^2-x^3\right)^9}\\
> &=[x^8]\sum_{{k_1+k_2+k_3}\atop{k_1,k_2,k_3\geq 0}}\binom{9}{k_1,k_2,k_3}1^{k_1}\left(x^2\right)^{k_2}\left(-x^3\right)^{k_3}\\
> &=[x^8]\sum_{{k_1+k_2+k_3}\atop{k_1,k_2,k_3\geq 0}}\binom{9}{k_1,k_2,k_3}(-1)^{k_3}x^{2k_2+3k_3}\\
> &=\binom{9}{5,4,0}(-1)^0+\binom{9}{6,1,2}(-1)^2\tag{1}\\
> &=\frac{9!}{5!4!0!}+\frac{9!}{6!1!2!}\\
> &=126+252\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=378}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we select the coefficient of $x^8$. We also note the sum of the entries of the lower indices of the multinomial coefficient is $9$ (i.e. $5+4+0=6+1+2=9$).

> **Binomial theorem (twice):**
>
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{[x^8]}&\color{blue}{\left(1+x^2-x^3\right)^9}\\
> &=[x^8]\sum_{k=0}^9\binom{9}{k}\left(x^2+x^3\right)^k\\
> &=[x^8]\sum_{k=0}^9\binom{9}{k}x^{2k}\left(1+x\right)^k\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^4\binom{9}{k}x^{2k}[x^{8-2k}]\left(1+x\right)^k\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^4\binom{9}{k}\binom{k}{8-2k}\tag{3}\\
> &=\binom{9}{3}\binom{3}{2}+\binom{9}{4}\binom{4}{0}\tag{4}\\
> &=252+126\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=378}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (2) we apply the rule $[x^{p-q}]A(x)=[x^p]x^qA(x)$ and set the upper limit of the sum to $4$ since the exponent of $x^{8-2k}$ is non-negative.
- In (3) we select the coefficient of $x^{8-2k}$.
- In (4) we select the non-zero terms of (3) noting that $\binom{p}{q}=\frac{p(p-1)\cdots(p-q+1)}{q!}=0$ if $q>p$.

Answer (score 1):

The required coefficient should be

$$\binom90\binom94+\binom92\binom71$$

Using  binomial expansion of $$((1+x^2)+(-x^3))^9$$

Comment: @Peter, I don't see $\binom71$ there

Comment: So I could have picked similarly $\binom90\binom94+\binom91\binom82$ ?

Comment: @ lab bhattacharjee maybe because after we picked the 2 elements out of 9 were left to work with 7 elements in total from which we will pick a single element

Comment: @Ea97, Didn't get your first question

Comment: the main question? or the second one?

Comment: @Ea97, main question

Comment: @ lab bhattacharjee I need to find the binomial coefficient of $x^8$ in the expansion of $(1+x^2-x^3)^9$.. I was trying to solve it using the multinomial theorem but my results seem way too big for me.

Answer (score 0):

Using multinomial theorem you should get after your correct calculations of the possible combinations for getting the exponent $8$ the following:

- Using the color code: $\color{green}{1} + \color{blue}{x^2} \color{orange}{-x^3}$

$$\binom{9}{\color{green}{5},\color{blue}{4},\color{orange}{0}} + \color{orange}{(-1)^2}\binom{9}{\color{green}{6},\color{blue}{1},\color{orange}{2}} = \frac{9!}{5!\cdot 4! \cdot 0!} + \frac{9!}{6!\cdot 1! \cdot 2!} = \boxed{378}$$